# ViewPager2 + FragmentStateAdapter: change pages

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

I'm using `ViewPager2` with a `FragmentStateAdapter`. Something like this,

```
   class TicketsPagerAdapter(f: Fragment, private var pages: Int): FragmentStateAdapter(f) {
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return pages
        }

        override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
            return TicketsFragment.newInstance(position)
        }

    }
```

I want to tell the adapter to change it's data set (add a page, remove a page, clear all pages, etc). I've tried calling `notifyDataSetChanged` and that has no affect.

Re-creating the adapter and setting the new instance into the `ViewPager2` **does** work, but that obviously causes the entire view pager + all pages to re-draw themselves.

Comment: What are you doing in TicketsFragment.newInstance(position) ?

Comment: Just returns a new instance of a fragment.